# PDF of sum of stationary processes

Tags: density-function, stochastic-processes, stationarity, convolution

I would like to obtain formulas for the sum of random processes $U(\omega,t), V(\omega,t)$:

Sum of two signals: $G(\omega,t) = U(\omega,t) + V(\omega,t)$

Case 1: $U,V$ are also jointly stationary
$p_G(g)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} p_{U,V}(x,g-x)dx$. Is this correct?

Case 2: $U,V$ are just each individually (and not jointly) stationary. I guess in this case also G is not necessarily stationary.
How to obtain the density $p_G(g,t)$ in this case?

Comment: Hi: It my depend on the specific stationarity that you're referring to ( there are a few: strong, weak and maybe others )  but, for the weakest one ( constant mean, constant variance ), the sum of two stationary series is always stationary.